# Send Excel range including chart by email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm having problems modifying a macro to instead copy a selected range of data and send it by e-mail to a specific address.

I'm starting with the following working code:

```
Sub Mail_Range()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
Dim Source As Range
Dim Dest As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set Source = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Source = Range("A1:K50").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Source Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

Source.Copy
With Dest.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Selection of " & wb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    'You use Excel 97-2003
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    'You use Excel 2007-2016
    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
End If

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Dest
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

The questions are:

1) How do I copy any charts that are in the specific range?

2) How do I put the copied range in the .Body area?

Comment: When you say does not put the copied range in the `.body` area, what are you trying to achieve exactly? You put the copied area into a new workbook, attached that to the email, and in the body of the email just write "Hi There".

Comment: in this example yes, this was the base e-mail copied from another site. The main goal is to paste all the selected data from the specific range in the body area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the full Office installed, then you could using the Word editor within Outlook to achieve this. This Word editor can paste copied Excel ranges either as linked Excel ranges or as multiple other objects which can be specified using [WdPasteDataType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237933%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Example:

Having the active Excel sheet like:

[image]

Code like this:

```
Sub emailer()

 'get Outlook Application
 Dim oOlApp As Object
 On Error Resume Next
 Set oOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
 On Error GoTo 0
 If oOlApp Is Nothing Then
  Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 End If

 olMailItem = 0
 Set oOlMItem = oOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

 'get Excel cell range which shall be in the mail
 Set oWB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set oWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Set oRange = oWS.Range("A1:H17")
 oRange.Copy ' Range is now in Clipboard

 With oOlMItem

  .Display

  .To = "email@email.com"
  .Subject = "Subject"

  Set oOlInsp = .GetInspector
  Set oWdDoc = oOlInsp.WordEditor ' get Word Document from the MailBody

  olFormatRichText = 3
  .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText ' change to RichTextFormat

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
  oWdRng.InsertBefore "This is before the Excel table."
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range

  'oWdRng.Paste ' paste Excel range from Clipboard as linked Excel range

  wdInLine = 0
  wdPasteEnhancedMetafile = 9
  wdPasteOLEObject = 0

  'paste Excel range from Clipboad as OLEObject
  oWdRng.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject
  'paste Excel range from Clipboad as EnhancedMetafile
  'oWdRng.PasteSpecial Placement:=wdInLine, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile

  oWdRng.InsertParagraphAfter

  Set oWdRng = oWdDoc.Paragraphs(oWdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
  oWdRng.InsertBefore "This is after the Excel table."


 End With

 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

produces this mail in Outlook:

[image]

Comment: nice code , but now another issue pops-up. Some Colors of the chart appear faded....washed out ... It there any solution ?

Comment: Please be more precise. What Chart? What colors? Which `WdPasteDataType` is used? Maybe you could provide a small complete verifiable example which shows the issue.

Comment: the bar chart , i see the problem is at the red color when using transparency option 15 % or more . I used your provided code and changed only the Range.      DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject

Comment: You say a rectangle filled with red color, which is semi transparent, appears faded, washed out? Whow, what a surprise ;-). Btw.: `DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject`: what happens if you double click the object so Excel is starting and enabling editing the object? Always faded, washed out?

Comment: they appear ok when accessing them. No problem in editing them. Another spotted issues is that while having the bar chart , I added a text rotated with the orientation option : "Rotate text up". In the email the text in the chart is displayed as orientation option : "Vertical Text".

Comment: @Alex Goaga: Well, your "issues" seems a little bit ... to me. So wait until another user here will provide a more suitable code to you.